# Selecting a sublist from list of lists after using Sentence Tokenizer

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, sentence

So i have some sentences in a list like:

```
some_list = ['Joe is travelling via train.' 
             'Joe waited for the train, but the train was late.'
             'Even after an hour, there was no sign of the 
              train. Joe then went to talk to station master about the 
              train's situation.']
```

Then i used nltk's Sentence tokenizer, because i want to analyse each sentence in a full sentence individually. So now the O/P looks something like this in lists of lists format :

```
sent_tokenize_list = [['Joe is travelling via train.'],
                      ['Joe waited for the train,',
                       'but the train was late.'],
                      ['Even after an hour,',
                       'there was no sign of the 
                        train.',
                       'Joe then went to talk to station master about 
                        the train's situation.']]
```

Now from this list of lists how can i select **only** the lists which have more than 1 sentence i.e 2nd and 3rd list in my example and have them in only list format as **separate lists.**

i.e O/P Should be

```
['Joe waited for the train,','but the train was late.'] 
['Even after an hour,','there was no sign of the train.',
 'Joe then went to talk to station master about the train's situation.']
```

Comment: with simple python code you can do something like this,
[item for item in sent_tokenize_list if len(item) > 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `len` to check the number of sentence in the list.

**Ex:**

```
sent_tokenize_list = [['Joe is travelling via train.'],
                      ['Joe waited for the train,',
                       'but the train was late.'],
                      ['Even after an hour,','there was no sign of the train.',"Joe then went to talk to station master about the train's situation."]]


print([i for i in sent_tokenize_list if len(i) >= 2])
```

**Output:**

```
[['Joe waited for the train,', 'but the train was late.'], ['Even after an hour,', 'there was no sign of the train.', "Joe then went to talk to station master about the train's situation."]]
```

Comment: This output is in lists of lists format, How can i get them in separate individual lists? See my O/P in Ques. Thanks!

Comment: as of now i have to take: output_list[1:2] to get the second sentence and then convert it to only a list, similarly for 3rd sentence. So will have to do this process individually for each sentence. is there any other way by which we can do it automatically ?